# Identify this script/handwritten font

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking for this font, I have tried What the font and Identifont as well as searches for script/handwritten fonts.

Edit, better image of the font

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the font through WhatFontIs

It is called [Give Away](https://www.ffonts.net/Give-Away.font)